# Replacing quotations to sentences

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to reduce some of the complexity of online text by removing non latin characters `+ [!?., ]`. Most of the characters can be removed without a problem, but for some of them I want specific rules:

Pair of `(` and `)`, pair of `"` (quotation marks) or a pair of `*` should convert whatever text inside them to a sentence if it contains more than two words. By converting to a sentence, I simply want to add a full stop at the end. For example:

```
but *after* I came up with it, I searched and...
```

to

```
but after I came up with it, I searched and...
```

Here I simply want the `*` removed, as opposed to:

```
 *buys airplane ticket* IM COMING FOR YOU
```

to

```
 buys airplane ticket. IM COMING FOR YOU
```

So in the first example, the author simply puts emphasis on a word that is part of that sentence, in the second example, the author describes an action that might as well be a sentence on its own. This works similarly with quotation marks, where one word is usually some sort of emphasis or sarcasm, while multiple are a quotation.

Is there a way to do this in regex (Java)?

EDIT:
So my general approach requires 2 patterns for each of the case the parathesis, quotation marks and the *. The first step is to handle the multi-words by running replace on `\*((\w+ )+\w+)\*` to `$1.` and then replacing all the `*` to nothing. This works, but I need 6 regex calls for this then. Is there a better way?

Comment: Your examples are both replacing all `*`s.

Comment: No, second example replaces a pair of \* with full stop at the position of last '*'

Comment: Simple answer: Yes there is. Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [ask]. Remember **SO is not a free code service!**

Comment: @JorgeCampos Added my current approach. It works, my question is if there are better ways.

Comment: Not sure if I get it right. You could probably combine the three "two or more words" replaces to one  [`"([\"*(])((?:\\w+ )+\\w+)(?:\\1|\\))"`](https://regex101.com/r/eS5zL6/2) replace with `$2.` and replace remaining `[*")(]` with empty afterwards. See [demo at regexplanet](http://fiddle.re/zxhbb6)  (Java).

Comment: @bobblebubble This is great! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The standard Java library has no built-in notion of what a full English phrase looks like (telling white-space apart from letters or punctuation is about as far as it will help you). Additionally,

- No regular expression can parse English correctly. Regular expressions don't do nesting well.
- You may have luck using a grammar-checker such as those built into common word-processing software. However, they still have significant error rates.
- While there may exist NLP Java libraries that implement robust parsing, they will still not understand context, and fail frequently.

So no, you cannot do that with Java, or with any other programming language (unless you have huge resources, NLP experience and training corpora to build from) -- unless you significantly relax the requirement of detecting *"whether a sequence of characters could be a stand-alone English sentence"*.

Comment: Yes, I know that, and my approach isn't perfect in the sense of actually understanding a language, but its a pretty algorithmic approach that I think works *good enough*. My question is if there is an efficient way of implementing the algorithm I described.

Answer (score 0):

So my current best approach requires 2*numCases Patterns and looks like this:

```
static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\*((\\w+ )+\\w+)\\*");
static Pattern remove = Pattern.compile("\\*");

public static String transform(String str) {
    String sentences = pattern.matcher(str).replaceAll("$1.");
    return remove.matcher(sentences).replaceAll("");
}
```

Running

```
System.out.println(transform("but *after* I came up with it, I searched and..."));
System.out.println(transform("*buys airplane ticket* IM COMING FOR YOU"));
```

Gives the expected

```
but after I came up with it, I searched and...
buys airplane ticket. IM COMING FOR YOU
```

Comment: If this is not a solution, rather include it in your question than put as an answer : )

Comment: @bobblebubble Ok, thanks. Didn't know where to put it since it is *a* solution, just not a very good one. So in case noone posted anything better, I would have to go back to this one.